# node/express retrieving html templates from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, templates, express, routes

Hi I'm new to node and I'm trying to make a simple blog.

I want to route /pages/:post to search a database for "post" and return an html template file that I can use as a partial.

```
var posts = {
  'myarticle': {
    template: partial1.html
  }
};

var findPost = function (post, callback) {

  if (!posts[post])
    return callback(new Error(
      'No post matching '
       + post
      )
    );
  return callback(null, posts[post]);
};

app.get('/pages/:post', function(request, response) {
  var post = request.params.post;
  findPost(post, function(error, post) {
    if (error) return;
    return response.render('posttemplate', post);
  });
});
```

and posttemplate is a template file like ejs (i'm not comfortable with Jade as of yet) that looks like

```
<html>
    <% include ../partials/header %>
<body>
    <% include /thereturnedpost %>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this possible? I've looked through documentation/tutorials but none of them are clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'l answer with codes examples from my current project

```
  <body>
    <%- body %>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
```

and

```
res.render('index', {
                body: content
            });
```

So your example is almost correct. After fetching the data from the database you send it to render function (in my case I render *content* ).
It is for the case when you keep in the db html string.

Also I can recommend you to use markdown (e.g. [markdown-js](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js)) for the blog posts. It may be simpler to write and edit well formatted content, and less information to keep (comparing to html).

Answer (score 0):

As per your coding, your blog post contents are static and are in template htmls.

If you get the data from db, you should modify your code such that the template file is with the HTML markup/ejs variables and send the data values separately.

This can be accomplished through ejs.renderFile method...https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs2

Hope it will help you...